# Drop log lines matching healthchecks from logs using promtail and loki

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I am trying to drop log lines from haproxy.logs using promtail that are matching the healthchecks so that I would only keep valid requests.

The log lines that I am trying to drop looks like these:

```
Aug 16 10:37:55 cat-nv-common-03 haproxy[1137]: 172.21.6.4:52930 - - GMT:16/Aug/2023:10:37:55 +0000 body:- HEAD / HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1 200 281 "" "" 52930 \207 jetty-front-80 jetty-front-servers-8080 cat-nv-common-03 0 0 30 30 --NI 2 1 \0 0 0 0 0 - - - 208.115.199.18, 162.158.175.64:35728 -
Aug 16 10:58:45 cat-nv-common-01 haproxy[1080]: 172.21.6.4:7066 - - GMT:16/Aug/2023:10:58:45 +0000 body:- GET /healthCheck HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1 200 247 "" "" 7066 \893 jetty-front-80 jetty-front-servers-8080 cat-nv-common-01 0 0 27 27 --NI 3 1 \0 0 0 0 0 - - - - -
```

I have set up a stage that should drop the above logs:

```
 - drop:
          expression: '.*(healthcheck | metrics | serviceCheck  | 127.0.0.1 | HEAD ).*'
```

But the lines are not getting dropped. Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
      - drop:
          expression: '(.*health[c,C]heck.*) | (.*metrics.*) | (.*/serviceCheck.*)  | (.*127.0.0.1.*) | (.*HEAD.*)'
```

Solved the issue.